# BufferedReader not reading the entire file and not exiting the loop

Tags: java, java-8, bufferedreader

I have ini file that to be read in my application but the problem is it is not reading the entire file and it stucks in the while loop.

My code:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

String line = br.readLine();
Properties section = null;

while(line!=null){
     if(line.startsWith("[") && line.endsWith("]")){
         section = new Properties();
         this.config.put(line.substring(1, line.length() - 1), section);
     }else{
         String key = line.split("=")[0];
         String value = line.split("=")[1];
         section.setProperty(key, value);
     }

     line = br.readLine();
     System.out.println(line);

     // To continue reading newline. 
     //if i remove this, it will not continue reading the second header
     if(line.equals("")){ 
         line = br.readLine();
     }  
}

System.out.println("Done"); // Not printing this.
```

This is what inside the ini file. The newlines are included so I add if the `line.equals("")`.

```
[header]
key=value

[header2]
key1=value1
key2=value2

[header3]
key=value

// -- stops here

//this newlines are included.


#Some text   // stops here when I remove all the newlines in the ini file.
#Some text
```

Output:

```
[header]
key=value
[header2]
key1=value1
key2=value2
[header3]
key=value
//whitespace
//whitespace
```

UPDATE:
I remove all the newlines in the ini file but still not reading the entire file.

Comment: you are only skipping ONE empty line, better ignore all of them. At start of loop, `if (! line.isEmpty()) { // do normal processing} // read new line`. Hint: better use `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)` as main loop, a bit easier to handle and not reading at different places.

Comment: Tried both but still not reading the entire file. In your 1st solution, it reads newlines and it is until the 1st `#some text`. In the 2nd, no newlines but it reads until header3 only.

Comment: You probably have horrendous exception handling code somewhere up the call stack that suppressed the exception you code is throwing. Fix that, e.g. by removing any try-catch blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless there's something you've not included in this post the logic won't get stuck in the loop... If the file you're using looks exactly like what you've posted, it'll hit either a blank line(because you're only skipping 1 blank) or one of the lines starting "#" and get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because those lines don't contain an "="... Simplify your while loop to this and the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions wont occur and it'll process the full file:

```
    Properties section = null;
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.startsWith("[") && line.endsWith("]")) {
            section = new Properties();
            this.config.put(line.substring(1, line.length() - 1), section);
        } else if (line.contains("=") && !line.startsWith("#")) {
            String[] keyValue = line.split("=");
            section.setProperty(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
        }
    }
```

Notice that I'm doing a `line.contains("=")` so that blank lines and lines beginning `#` are skipped over...

Comment: Thanks! 
But there is no ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions displaying in the console.

Comment: If there is no ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions in the console either you're swallowing them somewhere or your example file/code does not represent the file/code you're using. And @user85421 is correct, this solution isn't perfect as it will process lines beginning `#` which also contain `=`, changing the conditional in the `else if` to `line.contains("=") && !line.startsWith("#")` would prevent you processing comments containing "=".